# How to implement ACL at a group level? E.g. only teachers in school A can update school A's calendar

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-acl

Trying to solve the following problem using Spring Security ACL: only teachers in school A can update school A's calendar.

Is it possible to implement such permission structure without adding an ACL entry for each teacher to have update permission over that school's calendar (approach #1)?  Or is it possible to define school A group, assign every teacher in that school to that group and give the group write permission over the school's calendar (approach #2)?

Approach #2 is preferable because approaches would generate the same amount of records for a single item like the calendar, but if another item was shared (school A's message board for example) approach #2 would only require 1 additional record, approach #1 would require new records for every teacher and harder to maintain if a teacher is removed or added (2 deletes/2 updates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grant permissions in spring acl to granted_authorities.  Basically, by virtue of being in a certain group, you create a granted authority for that group (either explicit or implicit).  The users who are part of the group get the GA.  Permissions are assigned to the GA.  If the user is removed from the group, remove the GA, and they will lose the access.

Comment: what you described sounds just like what I am looking for, I am having a hard time figuring out how it will work for multiple schools.  Would I need to create a separate group for every school? Would their be a single granted permission for all the groups? Do you have any examples?

Comment: Solution details, simplified version: 
1) When teacher logs in, add roles ROLE_TEACHER (regular security role) and GROUP_SCHOOL_A (where A is the name of the school, it's a "dynamic" role based on what schools given teacher teaches at, could be GROUP_SCHOOL_<INSERT_SCHOOL_NAME_HERE>). 
2) Give WRITE permission to GROUP_SCHOOL_A over school object, ID 1234 for in the DB for example
3) When checking if teacher has access to write on a school's board, check for "does teach have WRITE permission on object 1234"

Comment: Yes, though I would use an immutable id rather than name if possible.  Within a school you might conceivably have different levels of permission as well.  I have found that doing a role per permission rather than arbitrary levels if helpful.  E.g. ROLE_SCHOOL_[ID]_ADD_COURSE and ROLE_SCHOOL_[ID]_ADD_STUDENT, etc...